# Webpack image loader encoding breaks

Tags: javascript, image, encoding, webpack, loader

Im trying to create webpack loader for image processing. It should be pretty starightforward: find required modules with  /.png$/ extension, write it to my test file. According to loader API, I recieve module`s content as a first argument of the loader function. But I don`t quite understand in what encoding I recieve it. PNG file is binary, as far as I know, but javascript strings are, by spec, UTF16 encoded.

I`ve written some code:

webpack.config.js

```
let path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module:{
    rules:[
      {
        test: /\.png$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: path.resolve('./loader.js'),
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  watch: true
};
```

loader.js

```
let getOptions = require('loader-utils').getOptions;
var fs = require("fs");

module.exports = function(source){
    fs.writeFileSync("my.png", source, "binary");
    return "";
};
```

As far as I concerned, my initial thought was that I can do something like read source to Buffer and set it`s encoding as UTF-16, and then write this Buffer to the file, but that didn`t work.

The question is what should I do with source to write it to the file and create valid png from source. Cause right now all I`m getting is a bunch of errors like "cannot open file...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon the answer and it is simply writing

```
module.exports.raw = true;
```

inside my loader. This way loader will really get raw buffer. Otherwise I get buffer recognized as if it was UTF-8 encoded. Pretty strange, considering tha javascript string are UTF-16 by spec